# fancyvrb alternate commandchars and \textcolor

Tags: verbatim, fancyvrb

The following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
test\textcolor{red}{foo}test
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

but the following does not:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=&<>]
test&textcolor<red><foo>test
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

I get this error message:

```
ERROR: Argument of \textcolor has an extra }.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.7 test&textcolor<red><foo>test

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

I've tried all combinations of backslash-escaping the command chars but no luck.  How can I use `&`, `<`, and `>` as the command characters?  (Or if it's not possible, why?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `\textcolor` expects an actual brace after it, not just a "group open" token: its definition is

```
\def\textcolor#1#{...}
```

(here `#1` would be the possible "color model" allowed by the syntax). You can do with another command defined in terms of `\textcolor`:

```
\newcommand*{\fvtextcolor}[2]{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}
```

This should work:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=&\[\]]
test&fvtextcolor[red][foo]test
\end{Verbatim}
```

Not with `<>`, I'm afraid: these two characters can't be used as delimiters in **fancyvrb** `commandchars` (I've already been bitten by this "feature").

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know why `<` and `>` can't be used as delimiters in `fancyvrb`?

Comment: I've never investigated deeply, but I suspect that some `\ifnum` or `\ifdim` is involved.

Comment: what is `commandchars` in `Verbatim`?

Comment: @Tiina Did you look at the documentation of `fancyvrb`?

Comment: @egreg for tex, usually where do you look for its document? I had bad experience when looked for some other packages. For open source project, usually they have an official site, but I found tex package usually has void official website.

Comment: @Tiina The documentation should be part of your TeX distribution, but you can also go to www.texdoc.net

Comment: `Tex distribution` I used tex maker so I should look up its `help`?  it has `LaTeX2e reference manual (May 2013)` but I am not sure if it includes every package.