# Alternative commandchars in fancyvrb

Tags: fancyvrb

In my Verbatim I need to specify colour for my code.

In this answer ([fancyvrb alternate commandchars and \textcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23091/fancyvrb-alternate-commandchars-and-textcolor)) the solution is to put this code in the preamble:

```
\newcommand*{\fvtextcolor}[1]{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}
```

and then use

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=&\[\]]
&fvtextcolor[blue][function]
\end{Verbatim}
```

My problem is the `commandchars`. `\textcolor` needs a pair of braces, but in my code I use all the pair of braces that is: `()` `[]` `{}`.

So is it possible to specify another pair of `commandchars`? Something like
`&fvtextcolor'blue''function'` or `&fvtextcolor"blue""function"`?

Comment: Yes, but you need two different characters: ``[commandchars=\&\`\']`` would use the backtick for the opening brace and the apostrophe for the closing brace. Any unused character is good.

Comment: So this should work &fvtextcolor`red'`test' ?

Comment: Sorry, *almost* any unused character. `:(`; I tried with `"` and `!` and it seems to work.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Can you post it as an answer, so I can mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In theory, any unused characters would do, but unfortunately for certain characters this conflicts with other parts of `verbatim` typesetting.

I've found out that

```
[commandchars=\&\"\!]
```

gives the expected result.

The characters that are likely not to work are

```
` < > , ' -
```

If you really need some of them, a workaround can be devised.